# WebSphere: list Name Space Bindings using wsadmin

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

I want to retrieve Name Space Bindings using a wsadmin jython script. Using the Name Space Bindings, I want to retrieve the properties of each of the name space bindings. For examples I want all the StringNameSpaceBinding given its scope.

I am unable to figure out anything and I am unable to find any documentation. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code outputs all namespace bindings of type String:

```
bid = AdminConfig.getid('/StringNameSpaceBinding:/')
bindings = bid.split("\n")
for binding in bindings: print AdminConfig.show(binding), '\n'
```